# is it possible to put the navigation arrows outside the swiper container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

Is it possible to place the swiper navigation arrows like in the picture? If yes, how? Just like this: https://imgur.com/a/9gEPbJE

I tried making stylized blocks and just classifying them as the original swiper arrows, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: You can use the swiper methods and an custom event to handle it: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-slideNext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Simply add markup for arrows of your choice. Use the selector in the Swiper declaration.

```
// HTML
    <div class="swiper swiper-carousel">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <div class="swiper-left"></div>
      <div class="swiper-right"></div>
    </div>

    // JS
    $('.swiper-carousel').each(function(){
          var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-carousel", {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-carousel .swiper-right',
              prevEl: '.swiper-carousel .swiper-left',
            },
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
              clickable: true,
            },
          });
        });
```